# How to access columns within a function in R when using dplyr and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to use R to create a function that allows me to plot data by specifying a feature.

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
EmployerName      EmployerId Address PostCode CompanyNumber SicCodes DiffMeanHourlyP… DiffMedianHourl…
  <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>         <chr>               <dbl>            <dbl>
1 ArtsBournemouth        12194 7 Fern… BH12 5HH NA            "1,\n85…             10.3             18.1
2 BathSpa                 1865 Newton… BA2 9BN  NA            "1,\n85…             17.2             23.7
3 BirminghamCity          2090 15 Bar… B5 5JU   NA            "1,\n85…             11.6              9.2
4 BishopGrosseteste       2097 Longda… LN1 3DY  NA            "1,\n85…              6.3             12.5
5 Bournemouth            15721 Melbur… BH8 8ES  NA            "85421,…             18.6             23.3
6 Bpp                     2289 Bpp Ho… W12 8AA  02609100      "85410,…              5.6              5.5
# … with 20 more variables: DiffMeanBonusPercent <dbl>, DiffMedianBonusPercent <dbl>,
#   MaleBonusPercent <dbl>, FemaleBonusPercent <dbl>, MaleLowerQuartile <dbl>,
#   FemaleLowerQuartile <dbl>, MaleLowerMiddleQuartile <dbl>, FemaleLowerMiddleQuartile <dbl>,
#   MaleUpperMiddleQuartile <dbl>, FemaleUpperMiddleQuartile <dbl>, MaleTopQuartile <dbl>,
#   FemaleTopQuartile <dbl>, CompanyLinkToGPGInfo <chr>, ResponsiblePerson <chr>, EmployerSize <chr>,
#   CurrentName <chr>, SubmittedAfterTheDeadline <lgl>, DueDate <chr>, DateSubmitted <chr>, year <dbl>
```

I then have a function called means that returns a dataframe showing the mean value of a particular feature in each year.

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
   year DiffMedianHourlyPercent EmployerName
  <dbl>                   <dbl> <chr>       
1  2018                    16.7 Average     
2  2019                    15.2 Average     
3  2020                    14.7 Average     
4  2021                    14.2 Average     
5  2022                    12.9 Average
```

And then another function that filters down to the highest and lowest values for a particular feature in a particular year. For instance,

```
top_n_bottom_k_by_year(n=2,k=0,selected_year = 2022)
```

Returns

```
EmployerName DiffMedianHourlyPercent  year
  <chr>                          <dbl> <dbl>
1 Buckingham                      41    2022
2 AeccCollege                     39.2  2022
```

My final aim is to try and then create a line graph plotting the specified feature for the selected employers over the years and the average for all employers.

For this I define a function as follows:

```
graph_maker <- function(df=complete_df,data_feature=test,unis){
  feature <- enquo(data_feature)
  p <- df %>%
  select(EmployerName,data_feature,year) %>%
  rbind(mean_funciton())%>%
  filter(EmployerName %in% unis$EmployerName|EmployerName=="Average")%>%
  mutate(label = if_else(year == max(year), as.character(EmployerName), NA_character_))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year,
             y= data_feature,
             group = EmployerName,
             colour = EmployerName))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_discrete(guide = "none")+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = label),
                   nudge_x = 5,
                   na.rm = TRUE)

  p + ggtitle(data_feature) +
  geom_line(data = means,aes(x=year,y=data_feature),linetype=2,color="black")+
  xlab("") +
  ylab(data_feature)
  return(p)
}
```

At the very top of my code I have the line

```
test = DiffMedianHourlyPercent
```

And then when I run

```
graph_maker(unis = top_n_bottom_k_by_year(n=2,k=0,selected_year=2022),data_feature = test)
```

I get the following graph, which has parts of what I want but is missing the y-values.

[image]

If I change the graphing function to just

```
graph_maker <- function(df=complete_df,data_feature=test,unis){
  feature <- enquo(data_feature)
  p <- df %>%
  select(EmployerName,data_feature,year) %>%
  rbind(mean_funciton())%>%
  filter(EmployerName %in% unis$EmployerName|EmployerName=="Average")%>%
  mutate(label = if_else(year == max(year), as.character(EmployerName), NA_character_))
 return(p)
}
```

And run it I get what I want in terms of the dataframe. For instance, running

```
graph_maker(unis = top_n_bottom_k_by_year(n=2,k=0,selected_year=2022),data_feature = test)
```

Gives the correctly filtered and arranged dataframe of

```
EmployerName DiffMedianHourlyPercent  year label      
   <chr>                          <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
 1 Buckingham                      37    2018 NA         
 2 AeccCollege                     48.4  2019 NA         
 3 Buckingham                      41    2019 NA         
 4 AeccCollege                     42.9  2020 NA         
 5 Buckingham                      40    2020 NA         
 6 AeccCollege                     37.1  2021 NA         
 7 Buckingham                      35    2021 NA         
 8 AeccCollege                     39.2  2022 AeccCollege
 9 Buckingham                      41    2022 Buckingham 
10 Average                         16.7  2018 NA         
11 Average                         15.2  2019 NA         
12 Average                         14.7  2020 NA         
13 Average                         14.2  2021 NA         
14 Average                         12.9  2022 Average
```

But the issue is then accessing the column values in for graphing.

I found a number of sources talking about using `rlang` and `{{}}` or `enquo` but I really don't understand how to implement it in my case.

Apologies for the very code heavy post. I am totally new to R and still quite new to programming.

Comment: The code is way too long. Try to provide only the relevant part

Comment: `test = DiffMedianHourlyPercent` should not run. Have you used something like `attach(data)` beforehand?